# how to call C++ dll function with int& and int* parameters from C#?

Tags: c#, c++

My C++ DLL have a function like this:

```
void func1(int& count, int* pValue);
```

this function will determine the "count", and put some values into the pValue int array which is the length of "count".

how can I define my C# code?  you can ignor the [DllImport ...] part.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ref `&` isn't going to happen as far as I've worked out.

[MSDN has the answers you seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx)

and don't forget to export your function from C++ as `extern "C"`

According to [MSDN: Default marshaling for arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28VS.80%29.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor2) on the C# side I think you want something like the following

```
public static extern void func1( 
  out int count, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)] int[] values );
```

Where `SizeParamIndex` tells .net which argument will hold the size of the array to be marshaled.

Comment: thank you, Greg. I have asked them to change the int& to int*. I am still confused by the int* PValue parameter. Here the C++ side means an array of int. if I use "[OutAttribute] int pValue" in C# side, how can I use array?

Comment: And also mentioned in that article: --There are cases when [OutAttribute] will be ignored. For example, [OutAttribute]int doesn't make any sense, so the [OutAttribute] is simply ignored by the CLR. The same is true of [OutAttribute] string because string is immutable.--- I cannot use [OutAttribute] with int?

Comment: OK I think I can use this: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Int32[] for those two parameters. Do I still need the [OutAttribute]? Those two parameters are really "out" type.